# Programmatically Refresh Excel Data Connections Without Interop

Tags: excel, openxml, sql-server-openxml

I need to programmatically refresh Excel data connections without Interop in VB.Net code. I am somewhat familiar with Open XML and how to create or modify spreadsheets, but I can't figure out how to just refresh the data (from SQL-Server) using code.

I tried looking through the Open XML Spreadsheet documentation, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this problem? Wondering about this myself.

Comment: No, I never did. This is a shame as it should be an easy thing to do.